# Machine learning algorithms for correct words formation from jumbled words

Tags: word, bag-of-words

https://www.google.com/search?q=jumbled+words&oq=jumbled&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.3399j0j9&client=ms-android-lava&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Can Machine learning algorithms solve the input dataset of jumbled words and form the correct words from them?

Comment: do you want to correct jumbled words or jumbled sentences or both?

Comment: Thanks Madhur. Only Jumbled words. Example : Input Jumbled Word : OXB. Output : BOX

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import permutations 
import string 
permutation_list = [] 
s = "BOX"
a = string.ascii_letters 
p = permutations(s) 
  
# Create a dictionary 
d = [] 
for i in list(p): 
  
    # Print only if not in dictionary 
    if (i not in d): 
        d.append(i)
        permutation_list.append(''.join(i))
        print(''.join(i))

import nltk
nltk.download('words')

from nltk.corpus import words
for word in permutation_list:
    print(word.lower() in words.words())

output - 
BOX True
BXO False
OBX False
OXB False
XBO False
XOB False
```

Comment: you can add custom words in a file,read it and extend the words.words (list type) to get a match of custom words.

Comment: Thanks Madhur. One Jumbled word can have multiple meaningful words. Can the algorithm work for the same given below? Jumbled word example : LOWF Correct words : FLOW, WOLF, FOWL. Also Can the algorithm work for a long word (many many characters) ?

Comment: if you ask a person that what is the correct word for LOWF, even the person would guess it wrong. It's difficult to solve ambiguity. You could check the part of speech, noun, verb, etc and select the desired output. This code would work fine for words with multiple words and repeated characters.

Comment: Thanks Madhur. Can there be any limitations to these code after rigorous testing of inputting english words where the word string length is long? https://www.google.com/search?q=long+english+words&oq=long+English&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.5423j0j7&client=ms-android-lava&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8 Note : The word is in the english dictionary, but is long in string length.

Comment: you can use generators instead of lists for faster execution, you can use specific models if you are looking for a specific genre of words, eg - scispacy nlp model for scientific words. also you can hit some apis of anagram webapps and get the output https://www.anagrammer.com/anagrams-of/nlp

Comment: Please upvote my answer if you think it helped you in solving the problem statement

Comment: Thanks Madhur. Will the above Algorithm & code work for Indian Regional languages viz Hindi, Gujarati, Bengali etc?

Comment: My code, won't work for language having non-english characters.

Comment: Thanks Madhur. Can we achieve this in Indian languages viz Hindi, Gujarati, Bengali etc and other languages viz French, Dutch, Spanish, Italian etc?

Comment: It can work on above languages , you can have to load nlp models of these languages, try spacy language models